# Windows 10 reinstalling windows app store falls

Tags: windows-10

I removed the windows app store for some reason. Then I try to reinstall it after removal, but it gives me error like this. I googled a bit but still cannot find relevant answers.

P.s. my firewall is okay and always running, so is windows updates. The services of both are running okay so it should not be the issues of these.

---error log-----

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-Appxpackage –Package Microsoft.WindowsStore_11711.1001.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_11711.1001.5.0_x6
4__8wekyb3d8bbwe\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered.
error 0x80070422: While preparing to process the request, the system failed to register the windows.capability
extension due to the following error: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has
no enabled devices associated with it.
.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] f35a13ba-82bd-0000-2f80-61f3bd82d301 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID f35a13ba-82bd-0000-2f80-61f3bd82d301
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Win ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Program File...ppxmanifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

Comment: Try the solution in this blog : [Windows Store (and all Store Apps) Crash Immediately after Launching](https://chaosfreakblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/06/solved-windows-store-and-all-store-apps-crash-immediately-after-launching/).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is late, but I hope it will help someone.
Had the same error today, but with the addition that the start menu wasn't working when clicking on it.

I could get it running again by enabling and starting the service "camsvc" (German: Manager-Dienst für den Funktionszugriff). It seems that the start menu is actually some kind of store app and needs that service.

Also the service provides the "windows.capability" and allows AppxPackages to be registered.

Comment: Then English name for camsvc is _Capability Access Manager Service_

Answer (score -2):

reinstall windows 10 and keep files. that'll do it.

Comment: This seems overly drastic, and worse, it fails to "solve" the problem but rather sidesteps it.

Comment: i know what you mean. but this is a solution. it's not like i could use, turn it of an on as my solution for everything. this does specifically work if you've messed your computer up.

Comment: You've already had the [same answer](https://superuser.com/a/1281541/213131) to this question deleted. That is the community's feedback that this is not considered an answer to the question. Too many deleted answers will result in an answer ban. You may be helped by learning how this site works. The [tour] is a great place to start.

Comment: I will resubmit a moderators comment to your equally vague answer that was already deleted “Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does not answer the original question. ”. We are not picking on you, nobody is targeting you, it’s only about how helpful or unhelpful the answers you have been submitting have been.  You have received feedback to your existing answers, that feedback should be used to improve your existing answers before you submit any additional answers.

Comment: OK, I must have accidentally taken a stupid pill this morning, because I do not see the emperor’s clothes. If the OP went from “State A” (Windows 10 with Windows App Store) to “State B” (Windows 10 *without* Windows App Store), and this (however arduously or drastically) gets them back to “State A”, how is it not an answer? And if I don’t understand your unhelpful comments, how do you expect this new user to learn anything from them? … … … And Ramhound in particular: if reinstalling the Windows App Store via an ISO is a good approach, how is reinstalling Windows (via an ISO) not equally valid?